Are there any open source GTO charts?
I'd like to do a bit of programming on my own and I was wondering: Are there any open source GTO charts that are widely available and free to use? For example, if I were to make an opinion for which hands, and how often, someone should, with 20BB, go All-in, Raise, or Call/Check vs. a small blind limp, are there any sources available online that are both trustworthy and updated not too long ago?

There are:

Clone of piosolver in Java: https://github.com/bupticybee/TexasHoldemSolverJava
Clone of piosolver in C++: https://github.com/bupticybee/TexasSolver

PokerStove is partially open source:
https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove
Engine is open source, but GUI is freeware available as a binary in the repository.

Not sure why this was downvoted, looks like a solid answer to the question. I've left a +1 on it. Welcome to the Poker Community @tla!
